# C# FakeItEasy and Method Chaining: Only First Call Is Recognized

Tags: c#, fluent-interface, fakeiteasy

I have a call to a factory interface that creates an `IMachine` in a command handler. This returned `IMachine` from the factory has methods that can be chained together to create itself inside of a builder class. The problem I am running into with `FakeItEasy` right now is that it only recognized the first call (which is `WithSpeeds`) unless I configure every method call to return a fake `IMachine`. Is there a way not to configure every single call or have `FakeItEasy` recognize every method call on the chain? I know I must be doing something incorrect because if i use `OrderAssertions`, and fail the order on purpose without setting up my fake machine, it shows calls were made to all the methods. Thanks for the help.

**Part of the Command Handler's Method**

```
public void Handle(FooCommand commandParm)
{
  var entity = new Entity.Builder 
  { 
    Machine = _factory.CreateMachine(commandParm.MachineName)
                .WithSpeeds(commandParm.ProcessingSpeed, commandParm.StartupSpeed, commandParm.ShutDownSpeed)
                .WithOils(commandParm.Lubrication, commandParm.FinishingOil)
  };
}
```

**Test**

```
[TestMethod]
public void HandleSetMachineSettings_should_build_machine()
{
  // Arrange
  var settings = CommandUtilities.ReturnFooCommand();
  var _factory = A.Fake<IMachineFactory>();
  var machine = A.Fake<IMachine>();
  A.CallTo(() => _factory.CreateMachine(settings.MachineName)).Returns(machine);

  // Act
  _handler.Handle(settings);

  // Assert
  machine.Should().NotBeNull();
  A.CallTo(machine).Where(x => x.Method.Name.Equals("set_MachineNumber")).WhenArgumentsMatch(arg => arg.Get<int>(0) == settings.MachineNumber).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
  A.CallTo(() => machine.WithSpeeds(commandParm.ProcessingSpeed, commandParm.StartupSpeed, commandParm.ShutDownSpeed)).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
  A.CallTo(() => machine.WithOils(commandParm.Lubrication, commandParm.FinishingOil)).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take it that `WithSpeeds` and `WithOils` both return an `IMachine`, yes?

The problem is:

1. `_factory.CreateMachine` returns one `IMachine`, `machine` from your setup
2. `machine.WithSpeeds` returns a fake `IMachine` that FakeItEasy makes up. This is *not* `machine`, but is a different fake, call it "machine2"
3. `machine2.WithOils` returns yet another fake machine

Your Assert block suggests that you expected the *same* machine to be returned at each step of the builder chain. Try inserting

```
A.CallTo(machine)
    .WithReturnType<IMachine>()
    .Returns(machine);
```

after `A.CallTo(() => _factory.CreateMachine()).Returns(machine);`

That way `machine` will keep returning itself, and the appropriate properties will be set on it and whatnot.

Comment: thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for. I can always count on you to help out with my `FakeItEasy` questions. I am coming close to 900 tests on this project and most of them are thanks to `FakeitEasy`, so I appreciate the hard work from you and your team.